# How to grab keystrokes in Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-3, gnome-shell-extensions

I'm trying to write my first Shell extension and - as every blog post out there - I am too struggling with the lack of up-to-date documentation...

Namely I am trying to grab all key strokes from the keyboard, and - looking at code online and old mailing list messages - it seems that until recently the correct way of doing was:

```js
const Shell = imports.gi.Shell;
global.set_stage_input_mode(Shell.StageInputMode.FULLSCREEN);
global.stage.connect('key-press-event', myCallbackHere);
```

However this doesn't seem to work.  Both the function `set_stage_input_mode` and the property `StageInputMode` seem to have gone, at least on my Fedora 24 running GTK 3.20.6.

**What is the correct, current way to have my extension grabbing all keystrokes performed by the user?**

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a correct way to do this at the moment. You could hack something together that is either X specific or Wayland specific or maybe you could patch Gnome Shell to provide this information.

For Wayland you could start at https://github.com/MaartenBaert/wayland-keylogger and for X you could start by looking at reusing the key detection from autokey (https://github.com/autokey/autokey/blob/master/src/lib/interface.py).

I can guess this is not the answer you were hoping for, because on IRC you wrote that you want to write a replacement for autokey. For getting input from an external program you can use `GLib.spawn_async_with_pipes` (https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs/GLib-2.0/GLib.spawn_async_with_pipes.html).

I wrote some time ago some Shell extension code to poll `xinput test` and log roughly what's happening (think any alphanumeric key vs left ctrl vs return key). You can look at that code here: https://gist.github.com/daniellandau/7679741bf8bbc5c345591593ca05e9f6. It's not robust enough for doing any kind of macro expansion so I'd recommend reusing the detection code from autokey.

In general the docs at https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs are the place to find API references for libraries usable from Gnome Shell extensions. I hope you get ahead with your project. Starting out writing extensions is frustrating but eventually very fun once you get the hang of it.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for this. I will check the links as soon as I will have some spare time for personal projects, for now thanks for having written this.  I will come back to this and approve/follow-up with questions. :)